# Rails force ssl only on specified controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ssl

I have a ssl certificate which serves https://secure.mydomain.com. I would like to use ssl only on certain controllers and not throughout my entire application. I have looked online and can't seem to find a complete and accurate tutorial on how to enable ssl for specified controllers.

I am aware that I can use the config ssl below but it does not serve me a purpose since it enables ssl site wide

```
config.force_ssl = true
```

How can I tell rails to only use ssl on a specific controller rather then my entire application?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this with constraints in routes.rb:

```
resource :account, :constraints => { :protocol => "https", :subdomain => "secure" }
```

Also, if you have many secure routes, and you want to DRY things up, you can create a `scope` for your secure routes:

```
scope :constraints => { :protocol => "https", :subdomain => "secure" } do

  ...[secure routes]...

end
```

Comment: what about the secure part of secure.mydoman.com would that be included also?

Comment: @coletrain I've updated the answer to include a constraint for the subdomain

Comment: do I have to enable force.ssl for this to work?

Comment: No you shouldn't since you're not trying to force ssl for the entire site. This will simply constrain particular routes to ssl and your secure subdomain.