# Rails app using force_ssl on entire site when it shouldn't

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ssl, nginx

Something has changed in my environment and I don't know why. I use SSL only for logging in through my sessions controller, which was working.

force_ssl :only => [:signin] unless Rails.env.development?

After logging in, a user is redirected to the home page, which should not be HTTPS. Now everything is be forced to SSL. In my production.rb file I set force_ssl to false, which it should be by default but that didn't resolve the problem.

I've also tried the solution posted here about using a protocol restraint in routes.rb which didn't work either.

[Rails force ssl only on specified controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14700182/rails-force-ssl-only-on-specified-controllers)

I've restarted nginx and unicorn several times but still forcing SSL. SSL is causing leafjs (map) not to work when my app tries to access its stylesheet and javascript from a remote location.

I could download them into my app but that wouldn't solve the forced_ssl problem.

My app is running on a DigitalOcean droplet, if that makes any difference.

Comment: If you previously had force_ssl=true in production.rb this will make the browser remember that all access should be over https

Comment: I thought that was the problem also but not the case. I've cleared my history and cache but it still happens, even if I manually http://....., it still is redirected to https:

Comment: I'm not sure if that would make the browser forget a previously seen strict transport security header

Comment: You are right. It didn't fix the problem. My browser is stuck on https for my site. I did resolve the issue. Somewhere is my site update process, my production.rb file got out of sync. I updated it online, uncommenting the line for setting force_ssl to false and it worked after restarting unicorn.